# Compare 2 Arrays and find difference with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to compare two arrays and find the differences to add a class to this elements later. Actually, only the first difference (Text Mining) will be found. The result should be 'Text Mining', 'Classification' and 'Test' will be send to markDifferences(diff).

**Arrays:**

```
array1 ["Text Mining", "Data Mining", "Classification"]
array2 ["Data Mining", "Test"]
```

**JS**

```
compareObjects(object1, object2);

function compareObjects(object1, object2) {
            if ( typeof object1 !== typeof object2) {
                console.log("two objects not the same type");
                return;
            }
            if ( typeof object1 !== "object") {
                console.log('arguments are not typeof === "object"');
                return;
            }
            for (var prop in object1) {
                if (object1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    if (object2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                        if (!angular.equals(object1[prop], object2[prop])) {
                            console.log("property " + prop + " does not match");
                            var dif = object1[prop];
                            var diff = $.trim(dif);
                            markDifferences(diff);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("second object does not have property " + prop);
                    }
                }
            }
            // now verify that object2 doesn't have any properties
            // that are missing from object1
            for (prop in object2) {
                if (object2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                    if (!object1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                        console.log("first object does not have property " + prop);
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: That looks array to me.

Comment: If your objects are Arrays do not use `for-in` loop to iterate over em.

Comment: You´re absolutely right! I´ve changed the description

Comment: It is same as with <any framework>. It's JS and has nothing to do with AngularJS. This was discussed countless times, especially for arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a lookup object and increment the value for each word in the first array, similarly decrement the value of the lookup word in the lookup object for the second array. Then filter out all the result whose count in not zero.

```js
const arr1 = ["Text Mining", "Data Mining", "Classification"],
      arr2 = ["Data Mining", "Test"],
      obj = arr1.reduce((r,w) => {
        r[w] = (r[w] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
      },{});
      arr2.forEach(w => obj[w] = (obj[w] || 0) - 1);
const result = Object.keys(obj).filter(k => obj[k]) 
console.log(result);
```

ES 5 Code:

```js
var arr1 = ["Text Mining", "Data Mining", "Classification"],
    arr2 = ["Data Mining", "Test"],
    obj = arr1.reduce(function (r, w) {
      r[w] = (r[w] || 0) + 1;
      return r;
    }, {});
arr2.forEach(function (w) {
  return obj[w] = (obj[w] || 0) - 1;
});
var result = Object.keys(obj).filter(function (k) {
  return obj[k];
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi Hassan, cool! Unfortunately I cannot use => arrow functions because we have to support old browsers